# Implementing a file upload function, unable to return submitted using csrf token

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement a file upload function.

I am trying to enter the title, description and upload a file and return this request.. to ensure it is working... however I'm getting the error '404 Not found'.

[image]

I am attempting to use a csrf token in my create.blade.php to produce a string of the data I am entering.. I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I thought my routes were right.

Can anyone help me? I appreciate it.

web.php

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function(){
        Route::middleware('can:create_files')->group(function(){
             Route::get('/files/create', 'DocumentController@create');
             Route::post('/files', 'DocumentController@store');
});
```

create.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/files" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
    <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

DocumentController

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.document.create');
    }

public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request;
}
```

Comment: Visit `/admin/files` and see if that's working.

Comment: @Dan yes it does

Comment: Remember to change the action path for your form to `/admin/files` too.

Comment: Thank you!!! Silly mistake. I really appreciate it